# Merge Archimesh Rail Window to Wall

Tags: edit-mode

[image]

I created my holes using the subdivision tool, then I added the Archimesh window and fit it into the hole.

How can I join the window to my wall? I want the windows to move with the whole building when I am moving it around the screen. I have already fitted the windows neatly in the holes I created using Subdivision.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Blender Stackexchange. Please [**add images**](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1081/23985) of your model **in edit mode**. You can do this by using the [**edit link**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/136827/edit) below your question.That would help us a lot to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way of doing this is to parent the windows' empties to the building by first selecting the empties, then the building, then hitting Ctrl+P.